# MATLAB Multi-Page GUI query

Tags: matlab, user-interface, multipage

I am currently developing a GUI for a m.file that I had already completed. The GUI will be one with multiple pages, with each page being a GUI on it's own.

On the master GUI, the user will make a selection on a radio button group with 2 options. Depending on the selection, the page order would be Master GUI > GUI1 > GUI2 > GUI3, or Master GUI > GUI1 > GUI4> GUI5.

Referring to an example from "http://matlabbyexamples.blogspot.sg/2011/10/multipages-gui-forms-combining-from.html" , I somehow got it to work, I am able to navigate from page to page as intended.

The problem now is that every time I return to the Master GUI to change the selection on the radio button group, it will re-open all the GUI and turn off their visibility to hide them again(basically what the program does when I first open it), which is not what I wanted. Being a new MATLAB user, I've got no idea why that is the case.

The following is the code segment for my master gui:

```
function varargout = StartPage(varargin)
% STARTPAGE MATLAB code for StartPage.fig
%      STARTPAGE, by itself, creates a new STARTPAGE or raises the existing
%      singleton*.
%
%      H = STARTPAGE returns the handle to a new STARTPAGE or the handle to
%      the existing singleton*.
%
%      STARTPAGE('CALLBACK',hObject,eventData,handles,...) calls the local
%      function named CALLBACK in STARTPAGE.M with the given input arguments.
%
%      STARTPAGE('Property','Value',...) creates a new STARTPAGE or raises the
%      existing singleton*.  Starting from the left, property value pairs are
%      applied to the GUI before StartPage_OpeningFcn gets called.  An
%      unrecognized property name or invalid value makes property application
%      stop.  All inputs are passed to StartPage_OpeningFcn via varargin.
%
%      *See GUI Options on GUIDE's Tools menu.  Choose "GUI allows only one
%      instance to run (singleton)".
%
% See also: GUIDE, GUIDATA, GUIHANDLES

% Edit the above text to modify the response to help StartPage

% Last Modified by GUIDE v2.5 14-Aug-2013 14:22:36

% Begin initialization code - DO NOT EDIT
gui_Singleton = 1;
gui_State = struct('gui_Name',       mfilename, ...
                   'gui_Singleton',  gui_Singleton, ...
                   'gui_OpeningFcn', @StartPage_OpeningFcn, ...
                   'gui_OutputFcn',  @StartPage_OutputFcn, ...
                   'gui_LayoutFcn',  [] , ...
                   'gui_Callback',   []);
if nargin && ischar(varargin{1})
    gui_State.gui_Callback = str2func(varargin{1});
end

if nargout
    [varargout{1:nargout}] = gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
else
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
end
% End initialization code - DO NOT EDIT


% --- Executes just before StartPage is made visible.
function StartPage_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
% This function has no output args, see OutputFcn.
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
% varargin   command line arguments to StartPage (see VARARGIN)

% Choose default command line output for StartPage
handles.output = hObject;
handles.s1 = InitialCostCalculation;
handles.s2 = PVSpecsInput;
handles.s3 = PVSummary;
handles.s4 = HybridSpecsInput;
handles.s5 = HybridSummary;

h1=guidata(handles.s1);
h1.next = handles.s4;
h1.prev = hObject;
guidata(handles.s1,h1);

h2=guidata(handles.s2);
h2.next = handles.s3;
h2.prev = handles.s1;
guidata(handles.s2,h2);

h3=guidata(handles.s3);
h3.prev = handles.s2;
guidata(handles.s3,h3);

h4=guidata(handles.s4);
h4.next = handles.s5;
h4.prev = handles.s1;
guidata(handles.s4,h4);

h5=guidata(handles.s5);
h5.prev = handles.s4;
guidata(handles.s5,h5);

% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);
handles.output;

set(handles.s1,'Visible','off');
set(handles.s2,'Visible','off');
set(handles.s3,'Visible','off');
set(handles.s4,'Visible','off');
set(handles.s5,'Visible','off');
guidata(hObject, handles);

% UIWAIT makes StartPage wait for user response (see UIRESUME)
% uiwait(handles.figure1);


% --- Outputs from this function are returned to the command line.
function varargout = StartPage_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles) 
% varargout  cell array for returning output args (see VARARGOUT);
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Get default command line output from handles structure
varargout{1} = handles.output;


% --- Executes on button press in Pg1Start_Button.
function Pg1Start_Button_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to Pg1Start_Button (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
set(handles.output,'Visible','off');
set(handles.s1,'Visible','on');
set(handles.s2,'Visible','off');
set(handles.s3,'Visible','off');
set(handles.s4,'Visible','off');
set(handles.s5,'Visible','off');


% --- Executes when selected object is changed in MainMenu.
function MainMenu_SelectionChangeFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to the selected object in MainMenu 
% eventdata  structure with the following fields (see UIBUTTONGROUP)
%   EventName: string 'SelectionChanged' (read only)
%   OldValue: handle of the previously selected object or empty if none was selected
%   NewValue: handle of the currently selected object
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
switch get(eventdata.NewValue,'Tag')
    case 'PV_Button'
        h1=guidata(handles.s1);
        h1.next = handles.s2;
        h1.prev = StartPage;
        guidata(handles.s1,h1);
    case 'Hybrid_Button'
        h1=guidata(handles.s1);
        h1.next = handles.s4;
        h1.prev = StartPage;
        guidata(handles.s1,h1);
end


% --- Executes on button press in Pg1Close_Button.
function Pg1Close_Button_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to Pg1Close_Button (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
close(gcf);
```

I would appreciate a lot if someone can let me know what I am doing wrong and to also provide me with a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following file exchange program ([`uiremember`/`uirestore`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24669-gui-with-memory-uiremember-uirestore)) that keeps track of the last change in your `gui`. Additionally, you can implement this function by populating `figure_closeRequestFcn()` (or any return button callback) with a "save state" routine as explained [here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/videos/2010/12/10/how-to-save-and-restore-state-of-a-gui-in-matlab/).

Comment: Let let me rephrase my problem. When I run the code which I had posted above, what happens is that it opens up all the other GUI pages involved, then hide them by turning their visibility to "off". I can then make my selection between PV or Hybrid and access the GUI that I want. But when I return to the master GUI again(not by closing the GUI, a back button is available) and select the other option, the program will open up all the GUI involved and hide their visibility just like when I first ran the code. I want to avoid having to open and hide the GUI every time I make a selection.

Comment: Would an `if` statment be helpful in this situation? `if strcmp( get(handles.s1,'Visible') , 'on') then`.

Comment: what would I be comparing then? I really am clueless about MATLAB GUI.